# T2 chip on 2018 Mac Mini causes booting Mac OS via Refind bug after unplugging power

Tags: mac, mojave, startup, efi, t2

Recently received new shipment of T2 2018 Mac Minis at work. I had to install the refind boot picker on them. Install is straightforward and successful but for some reason once I unplug the power cable to the Mac Mini  I am unable to load into the Mac OS via Refind without a strange reset password prompt bug.

I am assuming this has to do with how the T2 Processor works on new macs. It almost seems to be like a sort of SMC-Reset that happens on the Mac once I unplug the power.

But I am still able to boot up to the Mac via the Start Up Manager when holding down the Alt-Option. Actually doing this will clear up the bug and allow me to boot into the Mac OS via refind. The bug only shows up whenever I unplug the power cable.

Others have documented this exact same issue here: https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/1475e30077/
User MacHead posted a very insightful breakdown of how he tested this bug.

I thought it would be worth sharing this issue at stackExchange. I added some of the screenshots that user MacHead shared on his original post, where he shows what it looks like once the Mac OS boots up via refind, after unplugging the power,:

Image 1> Mac finally boots up to Mac after 3 to 5 minutes and user is unable to log in.
[image: Mac Password Prompt]
Image 2> Previous image shows how Mac suggests user to power off and on the Mac and it will boot into recovery mode. This will then prompt the user to reset their password.
[image: Recovery Mode Reset Password]

So To clarify this is my environment:

- Using T2 Mac Mini 2018
- Using Refind 11.4
- OS is Mojave 10.14.5
- Security Options in Recovery Mode set to No Security

This issue can easily be replicated. The steps are as follows assuming you are using similar environment

1. Turn on Mac, use refind boot picker to boot into Mac OS.
2. Mac OS Boots fine. Turn off Mac
3. Unplug Power Cable
4. Replug power cable, turn on Mac and try to use refind to boot into Mac OS
5. Mac OS takes long time to boot. Eventually does but entering Admin/user password does not work. Asks to boot into recovery mode. (Screenshot 1)
6. Go into Recovery Mode and It will prompt for a password reset of your admin user account. (Screenshot 2)

According to Apple there is an authentication process of the boot loader. I attached link and screenshots below: https://www.apple.com/mac/docs/Apple_T2_Security_Chip_Overview.pdf

> The Boot ROM code contains
>   the Apple Root CA public key, which is used to verify that the iBoot bootloader
>   is signed by Apple’s private key before allowing it to load.

So basically what I get from that is..
1. Boot Rom authenticates Apple's iBoot Signature with a built in Apple Root CA public key. Apple's iBoot bootloader is signed by Apple's Private Key.
2. IBoot then authenticates kernel and kernel extension cache signature.

[image: Boot Process for T2]
[image: Apple Description]

**Whats the question then?**

**Question 1**
So according to this boot process Apple authenticates its iBoot bootloader. Is it possible Refind causes a bug in this authentication process? Is it possible the Mac is still checking for the Apple Private key in Refind's Bootloader but it fails to provide it? It still lets Refind boot but then the Mac OS boot process sees this fail, Causing the Mac OS to prevent a user from logging in, claiming it will require a password reset?

**Question 2**
If question 1 is not the case, then is it when I unplug the power cable, I am inadvertently removing the T2 kernel cache signature from the boot up process, causing this bug to happen? How do we prevent this?